# operator() in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an object that has a mathematical function behind it.  It seems like a perfect candidate for `operator()`.

Specifically its a light that has a different value for each (phi,theta) position on the sphere.

Now the thing is, when inside the class, accessing the light function has this crunky syntax:

```
    double operator() ( double phi, double theta )
    {
        // compute light function 
        return sin(2*t) * cos(p) ; // (really this is implemented as a function pointer,
                                   // so the light function can be changed)
    }

    void functionThatUsesLightFunction()
    {
         double val = ( 2.0, 4.0 ) ;  // seems bad // Whoops!  Doesn't work.
         double val2 = (*this)( 2.0, 4.0 ) ; // ok
         double val3 = operator()( 2.0, 4.0 ) ; // no thank you
    }
```

But from outside the class, it gets this really nice syntax like

```
    foreach( theta on 0..PI )
        foreach( phi on 0..2*PI )
            val += light( theta, phi ) ;
```

Do you think I'm misusing `operator()` here?

Comment: Can't you define a (private?) method `compute(bla)` and call it inside `operator()`? Then you can call `compute` inside the  class and use the `operator()` outside.

Comment: The first mechanism does not invoke `operator()`.

Comment: I'm not a fan of `operator()`. Operator() is a method with no name: It is the emperor's new method (as in the emperor's new clothes). `operator()` looks just as ugly and just as naked from the outside as it does from the inside. What is wrong with a fully clothed function here, such as `illumination`?

Comment: @David: `operator()` doesn't look at all ugly if you want to create an object that acts like a function.  I agree that it makes very little sense if it's only for "internal" use, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you should define yet another function, say `calculate`, in the private section of the class, and call this function from `operator()` and other member functions. That way, you wouldn't be calling `operator()` from member functions, but you can still call it from outside the class. Somthing like this:

```
class Light
{
  private:
    double calculateLight( double phi, double theta )
    {
        return sin(2*t) * cos(p) ;
    }
  public:
    double operator() ( double phi, double theta )
    {      
         return calculateLight(phi, theta);
    }
  //...
    void functionThatUsesLightFunction()
    {
         double val3 = calculateLight( 2.0, 4.0 );
    }
};

//Outside the class
Light light;
//...
val += light( theta, phi ) ;
```

There is also a good advantage in adding `calculateLight` function, as you can choose a good name for this function, which increases readability. `operator()` adds nothing to the readability.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that for a simple reason to avoid duplication, both readability and maintainability suffers. Later somebody will decide to add/change functionality of `operator()` and they forget that `calculate()` is actually a synonym. There is nothing wrong or difficult about `(*this)()` or `operator()()`, they are quite readable, and not at all burdensome.

Comment: @Gene: Where is the duplication?

Comment: The duplication is that what if someone came along and changed `operator()` to be: `return calculateLight(phi, theta) * 2;`. Then `functionThatUsesLightFunction` would be doing something different than `operator()` when they should probably be using the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would use `operator()` here. You don't access any object fields in the body of `operator()` and neither you change object state. I'd rather create a static method or just a regular function...

Comment: This is really acting as a function object.  The OP says that in practice, `operator()` will invoke a function via a function pointer, which will presumably be a member variable.  That sounds like a very reasonable use of `operator()`.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: You are absolutely right from OP perspective, but I don't think this is the case where OP approach must be applied... For example, `sin` is just a function, not `class sin` with `operator() (double val)`...

Comment: @a1ex07: but as Oli said, see the questioner's comment, "really this is implemented as a function pointer, so the light function can be changed". In fact the `operator()` *does* access a data member. So you need to explain how a free function should replace this member function whose output depends on the current state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

`YourClass::operator()` as in `a.operator() (arguments)` as opposed to `a(arguments)` is pretty fine. It's just a matter of getting used to. Use it for a while, together with the C++ style casts, it will make you feel more pedantic and you won't be bothered by it afterwards.

Comment: Use Haskell then :). But don't feel that valid C++ is ugly.